# concatenating word documents and converting them to pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, ms-word, merge, documents

what is the best possible way to merge multiple documents and convert them to pdf. also we need to insert blank pages for every odd pages.

Comment: Do you need to do it i c#? It's trvial in VBA ...

Comment: C# would be fine. VBA would also do but prefer c#.

Comment: Ok. I'll wait to see if someone posts a c# solution. But be aware that **paging** is a tricky thing, so inserting blank odd pages needs extensive testing. Any modification from word to pdf in font size, margins, paper size, images, table borders, etc etc will ruin you output.

Answer (score 1):

A fully supported, server side automated version of this (mostly baked into the the MS camp though) involves using the OpenXMLSDK to do any field inserts, then using Sharepoint's Word Automation Services (SP 2010) to convert the documents to PDF, and then pick your favorite PDF toolkit (iTextSharp for me) for any post processing (merging documents, inserting blank pages, or images that must be positioned relative to specific pages).

The reason for doing the document merge in PDF rather than OpenXML is simplicity - you don't have to deal with merging styles, headers etc.

The reason for doing the blank pages and image insertion is that OpenXML has no idea how to render the content, and so it has no idea where page breaks would occur naturally (you can still insert breaks like you would in Word though).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C# and you are OK with a server based solution then [have a look at this post](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/12/converting-office-files-to-pdf-format.html). It uses a .net friendly web services interface.

There is an optional [SharePoint version](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/PDF-Converter-for-SharePoint/summary.aspx) available as well, but as you did not include a SharePoint tag I assume that won't be of interest to you.

Full disclosure, I wrote that post.